# $ \lfloor (2^{2})/3 \rfloor +... + \lfloor (2^{1000})/3 \rfloor = \frac{2^{A}-B}{C}$, minimum of $A+B+C$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$ \lfloor (2^{2})/3 \rfloor + \lfloor (2^{3})/3 \rfloor + \lfloor (2^{4})/3 \rfloor + ... +  \lfloor (2^{999})/3 \rfloor + \lfloor (2^{1000})/3 \rfloor = \frac{2^{A}-B}{C},$$
$$ A,B,C \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$$

What is the minimum possible of $A+B+C$?

---

**Attempt:**

We can easily show that if $k>1$ is even, then remainder of $(2^{k})/3$ is 1, and if $k>2$ is odd then remainder is 2. So the problematic summation will become:

$$ (2^{2}-1)/3  + (2^{3}-2)/3  +  (2^{4}-1)/3  + ... +   (2^{999}-2)/3  +  (2^{1000}-1)/3 $$
there are exactly 499 of $-(1/3) -(2/3) = -1$, so we get
$$ \frac{2^{2}+...+2^{1000}}{3} - 499  - 1/3 $$
$$ \frac{2^{1001}-4}{3} - \frac{1498}{3} = \frac{2^{1001}-1502}{3}$$
So one possible set of values is $A=1001,B=1502,C=3$.

Notice that the minimum value for $C$ is clearly 3 (because we cannot divide the numerator with 3). If we increase $A$ or $B$, then $A+B+C$ will also increased. So my argument is that $A=1001,B=1502,C=3$ make $A+B+C$ minimum. But.. notice that if we increase $A$ and decrease $B$, this makes more possibilites.

Comment: Which contest is this from please ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy winter camp olympiad for senior high school students

Comment: Since $2^{1001}-1502\equiv(-1)^{1001}-2\equiv0\,\,(\mathrm{mod}\,3)$, you in fact can divide the numerator by $3$.